# TP-LINK TL-WN725N can not work in kernel 3.2.0-40-generic under 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, kernel, realtek

TP-LINK TL-WN725N can work out of box in kernel 3.2.0-34-generic under 12.04 amd64.
After I update to kernel 3.2.0-40-generic , it does not work out of box in kernel 3.2.0-40-generic under 12.04 amd64.
I use ubuntu 12.04 amd64.
TP-LINK TL-WN725N chip is RTL8188CUS.

Is here anyone who meet the same problem ?
Thanks

Comment: Does the duplicate question not answer your question?

Comment: I do like that . But every time I pulled out usb wireless card or run 'sudo modprobe -r 8192cu', my system crashed. The 8192cu sometimes works, sometimes not. I think the drivers of RTL8188CUS in kernel and from realtek site are both very poor. The realtek site says the newest kernel that the driver supports is 3.0.8. But now my 12.04 kernel is 3.2.0-40.

Answer (score 0):

Make a bootable usb stick with 13.04 version, do a live session and see if it works.The 13.04 has 3.8 kernel which supports more hardware devices.

Comment: It still does not work out of box in 13.04 and 12.04.2 . I download driver of RTL8188CUS from realtex site and install it . If I use that driver from realtex site, ever time I pulled out TL-WN725N , system crashed.